# Why cv::parallel_for_ run faster than my own implementation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, compilation, openmp

I am **implementing the nearest-neighborhood resizing algorithm for RGB image** (unsigned char type). Considering the speed comparison with OpenCV's on Android ARMv8 platform, I find that OpenCV use `cv::parallel_for_` for multi-threading speed up.

Thus, I dive into the corresponding source code of OpenCV's `cv::resize()`, copy and paste the code that actually run, put in my `main.cpp`. It contains a functor `resizeNNInvoker`, and `cv::parallel_for_` that performs multi-thread calculation on this functor.

**What makes me confuse is that `cv::parallel_for_` version run faster than using `my_parallel_for_`, whose code keeps same as OpenCV's.**

To make it more clear:

- Tested on Android armv8 platform
- **Compiling OpenCV with OpenMP multithread, turn of other parallel framwork
- Go to OpenCV's `cv::parallel_for_`, change its source code to the same as `my_parallel_for_` (see below)
- Using 4 threads by `cv::setNumThreads(4)`, and binding 4 big cpu cores (using [ncnn](https://github.com/tencent/ncnn) API)
- All code compile under Release mode (via CMake)
- Test input image: width=7680,height=4320, target image size: 7680/3, 4320/3.

Time cost is as follow:

| method | time cost |
| --- | --- |
| cv::parallel_for_ | 3.24 ms |
| my_parallel_for_ | 7.67 ms |
| inplace openmp | 7.75 ms |

```cpp
// my own implementation of parallel_for_, copied from OpenCV source code
void my_parallel_for_(const cv::Range& range, const cv::ParallelLoopBody& body)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(4)
    for (int i = range.start; i < range.end; ++i)
        body(cv::Range(i, i + 1));
}

// The functor that performs nearest neighbor resizing, copied from opencv source
class resizeNNInvoker : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    resizeNNInvoker(const cv::Mat& _src, cv::Mat &_dst, int *_x_ofs, double _ify) :
        ParallelLoopBody(), src(_src), dst(_dst), x_ofs(_x_ofs),
        ify(_ify)
    {
    }

    virtual void operator() (const cv::Range& range) const CV_OVERRIDE
    {
        //printf("--- resizeNNInvoker get called\n");
        cv::Size ssize = src.size(), dsize = dst.size();
        int y, x, pix_size = (int)src.elemSize();

        for( y = range.start; y < range.end; y++ )
        {
            uchar* D = dst.data + dst.step*y;
            int sy = std::min(cvFloor(y*ify), ssize.height-1);
            const uchar* S = src.ptr(sy);

            switch( pix_size )
            {
            case 1:
                for( x = 0; x <= dsize.width - 2; x += 2 )
                {
                    uchar t0 = S[x_ofs[x]];
                    uchar t1 = S[x_ofs[x+1]];
                    D[x] = t0;
                    D[x+1] = t1;
                }

                for( ; x < dsize.width; x++ )
                    D[x] = S[x_ofs[x]];
                break;
            case 2:
                for( x = 0; x < dsize.width; x++ )
                    *(ushort*)(D + x*2) = *(ushort*)(S + x_ofs[x]);
                break;
            case 3:
                for( x = 0; x < dsize.width; x++, D += 3 )
                {
                    const uchar* _tS = S + x_ofs[x];
                    D[0] = _tS[0]; D[1] = _tS[1]; D[2] = _tS[2];
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                for( x = 0; x < dsize.width; x++ )
                    *(int*)(D + x*4) = *(int*)(S + x_ofs[x]);
                break;
            case 6:
                for( x = 0; x < dsize.width; x++, D += 6 )
                {
                    const ushort* _tS = (const ushort*)(S + x_ofs[x]);
                    ushort* _tD = (ushort*)D;
                    _tD[0] = _tS[0]; _tD[1] = _tS[1]; _tD[2] = _tS[2];
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                for( x = 0; x < dsize.width; x++, D += 8 )
                {
                    const int* _tS = (const int*)(S + x_ofs[x]);
                    int* _tD = (int*)D;
                    _tD[0] = _tS[0]; _tD[1] = _tS[1];
                }
                break;
            case 12:
                for( x = 0; x < dsize.width; x++, D += 12 )
                {
                    const int* _tS = (const int*)(S + x_ofs[x]);
                    int* _tD = (int*)D;
                    _tD[0] = _tS[0]; _tD[1] = _tS[1]; _tD[2] = _tS[2];
                }
                break;
            default:
                for( x = 0; x < dsize.width; x++, D += pix_size )
                {
                    const uchar* _tS = S + x_ofs[x];
                    for (int k = 0; k < pix_size; k++)
                        D[k] = _tS[k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

private:
    const cv::Mat& src;
    cv::Mat& dst;
    int* x_ofs;
    double ify;

    resizeNNInvoker(const resizeNNInvoker&);
    resizeNNInvoker& operator=(const resizeNNInvoker&);
};

// The entry function that calls nearest neighbor resizing with openmp multi-thread
void resize_nearest(const uchar* src_buf, int src_height, int src_width, int src_linebytes, uchar* dst_buf, int dst_height, int dst_width, int dst_linebytes, const Option& opt)
{
    cv::Size src_size;
    src_size.height = src_height;
    src_size.width = src_width;
    cv::Mat src(src_size, CV_8UC3, const_cast<uchar*>(src_buf));

    cv::Size dst_size;
    dst_size.height = dst_height;
    dst_size.width = dst_width;
    cv::Mat dst(dst_size, CV_8UC3, dst_buf);

    cv::Size ssize = src.size(), dsize = dst.size();

    double inv_scale_x = (double)dsize.width/ssize.width;
    double inv_scale_y = (double)dsize.height/ssize.height;
    double fx = inv_scale_x;
    double fy = inv_scale_y;

    cv::AutoBuffer<int> _x_ofs(dsize.width);
    int* x_ofs = _x_ofs.data();
    int pix_size = (int)src.elemSize();
    double ifx = 1./fx, ify = 1./fy;
    int x;

    for( x = 0; x < dsize.width; x++ )
    {
        int sx = cvFloor(x*ifx);
        x_ofs[x] = std::min(sx, ssize.width-1)*pix_size;
    }

    cv::Range range(0, dsize.height);

    // !! define the instance of resizeNNInvoker functor.
    resizeNNInvoker invoker(src, dst, x_ofs, ify);

#if 0
    cv::parallel_for_(range, invoker);   //!! use opencv's, cost 3.24 ms
#elif 0
    my_parallel_for_(range, invoker);    //!! use own implementation, cost 7.67 ms
#else
    set_omp_dynamic(1);    //!! use inplace-implementation, cost 7.75 ms
    cv::Range stripeRange = range;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(4)
    for (int i = stripeRange.start; i < stripeRange.end; ++i)
        invoker(cv::Range(i, i + 1));
#endif
}
```

Comment: many possible reasons. maybe it's not using OpenMP. maybe it is, but it uses different parameters. maybe it's something else. impossible to say. would require investigation.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html here is some information. Is TBB usable on ARM?

Comment: @Micka I'm not familiar with TBB. I don't think I need to figure out if TBB is usable on ARM, since OpenMP is bundled with Android NDK C/C++ compiler, OpenMP is usable on both X86 GCC/MSVC/Clang and Android NDK clang.

Comment: @ChrisZZ the question ist whether opencvs parallel_for might use TBB (and other techniques mentioned in the link) to reach the difference to your implementstion in your observation

Comment: @Micka I compile OpenCV with manually specifying `-D WITH_PTHREADS_PF=OFF`, `-D WITH_TBB=OFF` and `-D WITH_OPENMP=ON`, and in the cmake summary stage if definitely print `OPENMP` instead of TBB or PThread. Please don't keep doubt me that I didn't know how to compile opencv with custom flags.

Comment: @Micka The actually cause is as answered by me just now, due to OpenMP wrong config. The exepected behavior for my executable target, commonly, it should be one of: compile error, or compile and link OK and run OK. However, with previous wrong config, it compile and link OK(no error, not meaning very correct), but run result is without openmp.

Comment: Nice, how did you find out? Btw..I did believe right after you posted the comment to my answer. As you can see the comment here was from 11th of august and 3 hours older than the talk around my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figure it out. My OpenMP configuration in CMakeLists.txt cause that mismatched performance.

To be concrete, I build the executable `test` which depends on a static library `libplain.a`, and `libplain.a` compiles and links to OpenMP with these (the previous wrong one):

```
find_package(OpenMP)
if(NOT TARGET OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX AND (OpenMP_CXX_FOUND OR OPENMP_FOUND))
    target_compile_options(plain PRIVATE ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS})
endif()

if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND OR OPENMP_FOUND)
    if(ANDROID_NDK_MAJOR AND (ANDROID_NDK_MAJOR GREATER 20))
        target_compile_options(plain PRIVATE -fopenmp)
        target_link_libraries(plain PUBLIC -fopenmp -static-openmp)
    elseif(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
        target_link_libraries(plain PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
    else()
        target_link_libraries(plain PRIVATE "${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    endif()
endif()
```

Now change all the `PRIVATE` visibility to `PUBLIC`, then the openmp compile and link flags correctly propagate to the executable target `test`:

```
target_link_libraries(plain PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})

find_package(OpenMP)
if(NOT TARGET OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX AND (OpenMP_CXX_FOUND OR OPENMP_FOUND))
    target_compile_options(plain PUBLIC ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS})
endif()

if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND OR OPENMP_FOUND)
    if(ANDROID_NDK_MAJOR AND (ANDROID_NDK_MAJOR GREATER 20))
        target_compile_options(plain PUBLIC -fopenmp)
        target_link_libraries(plain PUBLIC -fopenmp -static-openmp)
    elseif(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
        target_link_libraries(plain PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
    else()
        target_link_libraries(plain PUBLIC "${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    endif()
endif()
```

With this updated cmake config, rebuilt program, `my_parallel_for_` get nearly same speed as `cv::parallel_for_`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code from OpenCV to select the actual threading framework:

```
#ifdef CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK
#if defined HAVE_TBB

#if TBB_INTERFACE_VERSION >= 8000
        tbbArena.execute(pbody);
#else
        pbody();
#endif

#elif defined HAVE_HPX
        pbody();

#elif defined HAVE_OPENMP

        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(numThreads > 0 ? numThreads : numThreadsMax)
        for (int i = stripeRange.start; i < stripeRange.end; ++i)
            pbody(Range(i, i + 1));

#elif defined HAVE_GCD

        dispatch_queue_t concurrent_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_apply_f(stripeRange.end - stripeRange.start, concurrent_queue, &pbody, block_function);

#elif defined WINRT

        Concurrency::parallel_for(stripeRange.start, stripeRange.end, pbody);

#elif defined HAVE_CONCURRENCY

        if(!pplScheduler || pplScheduler->Id() == Concurrency::CurrentScheduler::Id())
        {
            Concurrency::parallel_for(stripeRange.start, stripeRange.end, pbody);
        }
        else
        {
            pplScheduler->Attach();
            Concurrency::parallel_for(stripeRange.start, stripeRange.end, pbody);
            Concurrency::CurrentScheduler::Detach();
        }

#elif defined HAVE_PTHREADS_PF

        parallel_for_pthreads(pbody.stripeRange(), pbody, pbody.stripeRange().size());

#else

#error You have hacked and compiling with unsupported parallel framework

#endif

        ctx.finalize();  // propagate exceptions if exists
        return;
#endif // CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK
```

So this is the order of priorization:

1. TBB task arena
2. TBB
3. HPX
4. OPENMP
5. Apple GCD
6. WINRT concurrency
7. Windows Concurrency
8. PThread

Maybe your opencv parallel_for uses TBB while your code uses OpenMP?

Not sure whether it is possible, but you could try to use openmp from opencv explicitly, like `cv::parallel::openmp::parallel_for` in C++

Comment: The order you paste is correct, however, what I have tryied is, I put the openmp's implementation part to the very begging of `cv::parallel_for_`, instead of keep it original. I also tried remove all other backend macro determination and implementations inside `parallel_for_` and `parallel_for_impl`, but still faster than `my_parallel_for`.

Comment: If you are already changing openCV source code and rebuilding the library, can you add some debug code to 1. verify that the openmp code lines are executed 2. extract openmp settings?

Comment: Yes, before I ask this question, I added printf code to verify the openmp code is running, already verified openmp code lines are executed, then I ask this question. I don't know what you mean extract openmp settings, before I ask this question, I read the opencv source file, notice one static variable which obtained from a function, and inside this function, `set_omp_dynamic(1);` is called, thus in my pasted in-place calling openmp part, I explicitly call it.

Comment: For example the number of threads used. You call #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(4)
   OpenCV calls #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(numThreads > 0 ? numThreads : numThreadsMax)
     Which values are numThreads and numThreadsMax?

Comment: How expensive is set_omp_dynamic(1)? Can you remove that from the region where you measure time? Move it to some initialization phase.

Comment: Re: to MIcka: I use `4` as number of threads, whether using OpenCV or my implementation. To be precise. `cv::setNumThreads(4)`. This is what I already put in the question description.

Comment: how can you be sure that `cv::parallel_for_(range, invoker);` has 4 threads? Can you show the OpenCV code that you've changd? Did you change this line of code from the original opencv code? `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(numThreads > 0 ? numThreads : numThreadsMax)`? What exaclty does `cv::setNumThreads` do? In the docs it says `OpenMP - No special defined behaviour.` https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gae78625c3c2aa9e0b83ed31b73c6549c0

Comment: can you add/print `omp_get_thread_num` in your parallel region, like in https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_openmp/openmp_functions.html and test for your_parallel_for and cv::parallel_for whether it shows the same values?

Comment: Re: to Micka: I think you found the documentation for `cv::setNumThreads` but you wrongly focus your attention. `OpenMP - No special defined behaviour.` this tell us it won't do anything special. OpenCV will try to set the number of threads for the next parallel region. For TBB or other frameworks, there will be special cases that user specified number of threads not working, but for OpenMP, there is no special case.

Comment: I would recommend to verify those assumptions. And did you try to move the setNumThreads outside of your time-measured area?

Comment: Re: to Micka: The `setNumThreads` is outside of my time-measured area. I keep it outside all the time, didn't put it inside.

Comment: Ok. Did you verify the actually used number of threads with omp_get_thread_num in your parallel region and in opencv?